# Combination of lambda function and np.array with a constant doesnt work

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I defined these two functions:

```
function = lambda x: np.array([x, np.sin(x) + 0.01 * x ** 2]) # function
function_der_1 = lambda x: np.array([1, np.cos(x) + 0.02 * x]) # first derivative

#Defining range of x
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)

#Plotting 
plt.plot(*function(x))
```

[image: Plot]

This all works fine. But calling

```
x_1, y_1 = function_der_1(x)
```

does not work.

It returns an array of the form [1, array([...])].

Why does it not return an array of ones? I guess the reason is because the 1 is constant but it should work nevertheless, shouldn't it?

The wanted output looks like this (called with [1, 3, 4]):

```
[array([1.        , 0.56030231]),
 array([ 1.       , -0.9299925]),
 array([ 1.        , -0.57364362])]
```

Comment: What values do you expect it to return? What should be the values at x_ 1 and y_1? Can you provide an expected output in a numpy array format?

Comment: No, it should not work like that.

Comment: Your use of `lambda` has obscured the core issue, which is simply illustrated with: `np.array([1, np.arange(4)])`.  You can't make a 2d array from a mix of scalar and array, or even arrays of different sizes.  At best you get this Warning and an object dtype array.  That's essentially a list of the two items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set up was probably not good. I rearranged to

```
function = lambda x: np.sin(x) + 0.01 * x ** 2
function_der_1 = lambda x: np.cos(x) + 0.02 * x
function_der_2 = lambda x: - np.sin(x) + 0.02
```

The derivatives of the function f(t) = (t, np.sin(t) + 0.01 * t ** 2) will alway be of the form (1, ...) so I guess as long as I don't use another parametrization it should work.

Comment: This a cleaner approach ;) .

Answer (score 1):

In `function`, the input `x` is an array and `np.array` is called with two array in parameter so Numpy concatenates the arrays. In `function_der_1`, `np.array` is called with a list of two completely different object: an integer `1` and an array. Numpy do not know what to do with that and decide to create an array of object which contains the two objects. This is not great to do that. In fact Numpy show a warning to say that this is likely an issue:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

To create an array of `1` with a type/shape similar to `x` like in `function`, you need to use for example `np.ones_like`. Note that this is better to use function like `np.vstack`, `np.hstack` or `np.concatenate` in such case to specify you intent to Numpy (it helps readers and produces a faster code too). Here is the resulting code:

```py
function_der_1 = lambda x: np.vstack([np.ones_like(x), np.cos(x) + 0.02 * x])
```

Comment: The problem is that this is only an example. The case that the first entry will be constant wont be true for other cases. The error message only addresses the ndarray creation or am I wrong? Thank you very much for your explanation of the problem :)

Comment: I will probably just use ```list(map(function_der_1, x)))``` even though this is not very clean

Comment: The error is related to the fact that the Numpy function `np.array` does not know how to interpret the input because it is ambiguous. It ask you to be more explicit using a `dtype=object` assuming you want the provided result (which what apparently not the case).